# jar and data storage (excel, mssql or mysql)

Tags: sql, database, excel, jar, store

I am writing a jar file that will calculate the value of enthalpy of steam at specific pressure, temperature and dryness fraction.
  I will have to search the corresponding enthalpy in steam table.

to say simply there will be **three parameters** and the **fourth parameter** will be **selected from the steam table database or any other storage**.

But if I store the **steam table in sql**, and I create the jar file, then will that jar file be portable? Will the database be embedded in jar? And will it run without sql installed in other computers?

Is storing the **table in excel** good option? And how will I select the required value from excel? I sure cannot do

```
select * from steam_table where pressure=$a
```

or something like this in excel...
So what people do to store data in jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did connect java with excel uing odbc **without** any apache poi.
You just have to make excel as data source using control panel.

(Control Panel/Administrative tools/Data Sources(ODBC))
And add excel as data source .

And then make a normal connection to excel as you would do to sql.

Even the query to be passed to get an element in excel is same as that of sql.

Cheers!